# Multidimensional Array trouble (bounds)

Tags: c++, arrays

here is the code with the problem:

```
#ifndef WEAPONS_H_INCLUDED
#define WEAPONS_H_INCLUDED
#include "Battleship header.h"

void Player::torpedo(string enemyEvtTracker[][10], string myhitboard[][10])
{
    string bcn; //board column number
    cout << "Enter board column number (1-9): "; cin >> bcn; flush();
    if(bcn!="1"&&bcn!="2"&&bcn!="3"&&bcn!="4"&&bcn!="5"&&bcn!="6"&&bcn!="7"&&bcn!="8"&&bcn!="9")
    {cout <<endl<< "That is not a valid number.";}
    return;
}



#endif // WEAPONS_H_INCLUDED
```

here is the class Player:

```
#ifndef BATTLESHIPPLAYERCLASS_H_INCLUDED
#define BATTLESHIPPLAYERCLASS_H_INCLUDED
using namespace std;
class Player // define a class for a player
{
    void torpedo(string enemyEvtTracker[10][10], string myhitboard[10][10]);
    void cannon();
    void scatter();
    void menu();
    friend int main(int, char*[]);   //Let main access the protected members
    friend int routine_END(void);
    public:
    void displaydata()
    {cout << money << endl << gunpowder << endl << ammo_cannon << endl << ammo_4hit << endl;}
    string savename;
    int gunpowder;
    int ammo_cannon;
    int ammo_4hit; string gun_4;
    int ammo_scatter; string gun_s;
    int money;
    Player(string name){money=18000; gunpowder=100;ammo_cannon=20; ammo_4hit=0; ammo_scatter=0; gun_4="OFF"; gun_s="OFF";playername=name;}  //Define the constructor
    void simplegame(void) {gunpowder=99999999; ammo_cannon=999999999; ammo_scatter=4; gun_s="ON";}
    void getname(string *playername, int option)
    {
        if (option==1)
        {cout << "Enter your name here player 1:"; cin >> *playername;}
        else {cout << "Enter your name here player 2:"; cin >> *playername;}
    }
    string playername;
    char mainRowGuess;
    int check_transaction (int mymoney, int moneyowed)
    {
        if (mymoney-moneyowed<<0) {return 0;}
        else {return 1;}
    }
    void change_Answer_to_number(char row,int* outputRow)
    {
            if (row=='A'||row=='a'){*outputRow =1;}
       else if (row=='B'||row=='b'){*outputRow =2;}
       else if (row=='C'||row=='c'){*outputRow =3;}
       else if (row=='D'||row=='d'){*outputRow =4;}
       else if (row=='E'||row=='e'){*outputRow =5;}
       else if (row=='F'||row=='f'){*outputRow =6;}
       else if (row=='G'||row=='g'){*outputRow =7;}
       else if (row=='H'||row=='h'){*outputRow =8;}
       else if (row=='I'||row=='i'){*outputRow =9;}
       else {*outputRow = 0;}
    }
    void changeCharToNumber(char row, int* outputRow)
    {
            if (row=='1'){*outputRow=1;}
       else if (row=='2'){*outputRow=2;}
       else if (row=='3'){*outputRow=3;}
       else if (row=='4'){*outputRow=4;}
       else if (row=='5'){*outputRow=5;}
       else if (row=='6'){*outputRow=6;}
       else if (row=='7'){*outputRow=7;}
       else if (row=='8'){*outputRow=8;}
       else if (row=='9'){*outputRow=9;}
       else {cout << "Unexpected Error." << endl; *outputRow=0;}

    }
  char airRowStart; char airColStart; char aircraftDirec;
  char destRowStart; char destColStart; char destroyerDirec;
  char subRowStart; char subColStart; char subDirec;
  char patrolStart; char patrolDirec;
    /// START MENU FUNCTION
    void error_money(void) {cout << "Not enough money!";}
    char startRowAircraftCarrier;
    char startRowDestroyer;
    char startRowSub;
    char startRowPatrolBoat;

    friend int routine_END (void);
    friend void menu (int* gunpowder, int* ammo_cannon, int* ammo_4hit, int* ammo_scatter, int* money, string* gun_4, string* gun_s);


};



#endif // BATTLESHIPPLAYERCLASS_H_INCLUDED
```

and this generates the following build log...

> ### -------------- Build: Debug in Advanced Battleship Obj
>
> [ 50.0%] Compiling: main.cpp
>   C:\Advanced_Battleship_Revised_5111\main.cpp:32:
>   warning: ignoring #pragma comment  In
>   file included from
>   C:\Advanced_Battleship_Revised_5111\/imputoutput.h:9,
>                    from C:\Advanced_Battleship_Revised_5111\/Battleship
>   header.h:3,
>                    from C:\Advanced_Battleship_Revised_5111\main.cpp:25:
>   C:\Advanced_Battleship_Revised_5111\/BattleshipPlayerClass.h:74:
>   warning: 'int routine_END()' is
>   already a friend of class 'Player'
>   C:\Advanced_Battleship_Revised_5111\/BattleshipPlayerClass.h:
>   In member function 'int
>   Player::check_transaction(int, int)':
>   C:\Advanced_Battleship_Revised_5111\/BattleshipPlayerClass.h:33:
>   warning: suggest parentheses around
>   '-' inside '<<' In file included from
>   C:\Advanced_Battleship_Revised_5111\main.cpp:27:
>   C:\Advanced_Battleship_Revised_5111\/BattleshipMenu.h:
>   In member function 'void
>   Player::menu()':
>   C:\Advanced_Battleship_Revised_5111\/BattleshipMenu.h:118:
>   warning: label 'GUNPOWDER_MENU_1'
>   defined but not used
>   C:\Advanced_Battleship_Revised_5111\/BattleshipMenu.h:166:
>   warning: label
>   'CIN_WEAPON_OPTION_SCATTER_CANNON'
>   defined but not used In file included
>   from
>   C:\Advanced_Battleship_Revised_5111\main.cpp:30:
>   C:\Advanced_Battleship_Revised_5111\/weapons.h:
>   At global scope:
>   **> C:\Advanced_Battleship_Revised_5111\/weapons.h:5: error: declaration of
>   'enemyEvtTracker' as multidimensional
>   array must have bounds for all
>   dimensions except the first
>   C:\Advanced_Battleship_Revised_5111\/weapons.h:5: error: expected ')' before ',' token
>   C:\Advanced_Battleship_Revised_5111\/weapons.h:5: error: expected constructor,
>   destructor, or type conversion before
>   ',' token
>   C:\Advanced_Battleship_Revised_5111\/weapons.h:5: error: expected constructor,
>   destructor, or type conversion before
>   'myhitboard' Process terminated with**
>   status 1 (0 minutes, 1 seconds) 4
>   errors, 5 warnings

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you should really cast bcn to an integer and then just test if (bcn <= 1 && bcn >= 9) for outputting an error message.

Comment: Post the definition of `Player` class.

Comment: Why is `Player::torpedo` missing a return type?

Comment: no, still doesn't work. It's weird because it does have bounds

Comment: @someguy post the exact error, line no. and all. And make sure the return type of `torpedo` is `void` in the .cpp file too.

Comment: Please look at Nawaz's answer.. It's the only way that you can get that compiler error.

Comment: Oh, it's obvious. .H: `void torpedo();` .CPP: `Player::torpedo(string enemyEvtTracker[10][10], string myhitboard[10][10])`. Just fix that and mark Nawaz's answer as the answer.

Comment: And also, how do you declare this specific prototype

Comment: Ok it actually doesn't work. Same error message:

Comment: @someguy - Show what exactly is present in `weapons.h` at line 5. If the given prototype is exactly present at line 5, you shouldn't get this error message. Also, why are you implementing member function definitions in headers itself or am I overlooking something ?

Comment: @someguy: There are lots of important details missing. Basically, you are not really doing what you are telling us (and what you believe) you are doing. Show us the whole declaration of class `Player`. What header file is it in? Why is your `torpedo` definition also in header file? (You shoudn't put external definitions in header files.) How are your headers included into each other? Etc.

Comment: I thought you could use member function definitions outside of classes with the scope operator: Class::Fn

Comment: Ok I figured it out. I didn't use the extern keyword for the member function decl.

Comment: NVM that not the problem. The problem was that the compiler was compiling a different file. I noticed because even though weapons.h was included in main.cpp, any blatent mistakes in weapons.h didn't generate the error msg they should have.

Comment: (I had two weapon.h files) in different directories

Answer (score 3):

```
Player::torpedo(string enemyEvtTracker[10][10], string myhitboard[10][10])
{
  //..
}
```

This is the *definition* of the member function. Where is the *declaration*?

My guess is that in the declaration you've not mentioned the size of the array, as you did in the definition. It seems you've written simply `enemyEvtTracker [][]`? See the definition of `Player` class, and verify how you've declared `torpedo` member function in it.

Comment: Sorry the player class definition is messed up. It won't format it correctly

Comment: Oh I forgot to include the arguments (array,array) in the prototype.